# Is おやすも from a dialect?

Tags: dialects, internet-slang

I recognize that it's another way of saying "good night," where does it come from?

Comment: Are you sure this is a dialect thing? Did you hear it out loud? I'm just asking because I've got a Japanese friend who uses this on chat just for fun (just playing with the sounds).

Answer (score 7):

「おやすも」 is used only by some residents of the region named インターネット.  It is not used in Tokyo or Nagoya, I promise.